# jQuery - Can I test if an item is hidden or shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden, visible

Ok, I know there are other questions like this on stack overflow, but this isn't the same.

I have this thing that I made with jQuery, and it's basically a stickman that walks around. So far, there's two states for the stickman. Sitting, and standing. I want to know how I could check if it's the standing picture is visible or hidden, so I can disable the movement when the standing picture is hidden. Here's the thing so you know what i'm talking about:
http://jsbin.com/okazof
Here's the code source:
http://jsbin.com/okazof/1/edit

Comment: Like `.filter(':hidden');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('#sitting').is(':visible')) {
  console.log('sitting is visible');
}
```

> **Edit**: [working-code](http://jsbin.com/okazof/2/edit)

Comment: Strangely, this isn't working. Try it in jsbin, if it works, link me.

Comment: @user2036003 check the link

Answer (score 0):

I would change your HTML to a div and use CSS classes.

By adding a class of sitting to the element you can have more control over the JavaScript and the CSS. For example;

CSS

`.sitting { background-image: url( ... ); }`

JS

`$( '#sitting' ).hasClass( 'sitting' );`